# Block Unsafe Content - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

I've allowed Chrome to Load Unsafe content for a site by clicking on the Shield icon. How do I block it again?
Anything in Chrome's settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome settings -> Advanced Settings search for **Enable phishing and malware protection** under **Privacy**.

Also have a look at  **Check for server certificate revocation** under **HTTPS/SSL** to allow or block unsafe content.

Hope this is something you are looking for.